# Liferay migration from CE version to Enterprise version: can't switch theme in control panel

Tags: themes, liferay, liferay-theme

I'm trying to test my liferay-theme with liferay EE 6.1.20. This theme worked on my current liferay instalation. I can deploy my Theme without any errors on liferay EE 1.2.0 server. Than if go to control panel and try to switch the current theme to my theme - nothing happens and I  see only liferay default theme on my page. I don't found any errors in the server log - I can't post any logs or errors hier, because I have no output with errors...

Can anybody help ?

Comment: ?? There is no Liferay EE 1.2.0. Could you check the version? Also, if you do have EE you could contact the support team. If you're on a trial, contact sales and they'll be able to help you

Comment: Another one? Could it be 6.1.20? Trial (->sales) or purchased (->support)? They will probably give you the best service and questions to figure out what's wrong: I didn't see such issues - in fact just this week I've used a custom control-panel theme, which worked just fine. To be sure it was not a temporary glitch in the matrix - did you restart the server or redeploy the theme? Which Appserver are you on?

Comment: the problem seems to be on the compass framework and liferay EE. We are using compass und sass and it works fine  on the CE but not on the EE. We are using Tomcat 7 Server

Comment: Liferay EE seems to be  non-compatible with themes developed with sdk-6.1.0-ce-ga1

Comment: you can declare the compatibility in the deployment descriptor. However, you should test if it works. I didn't try but I don't expect too many differences between both for the themes - so my first guess is a (more or less explicitly) declared incompatibility, not so much a technical one.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect too many differences between the two. However, the easiest way to make sure a theme can be deployed correctly is to use the matching SDK (e.g. 6.1.20), copy your _diffs folder to that one and compile the theme.

Make sure that Liferay's deployment descriptor `/WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties` specifically states that the theme is compatible with your version, otherwise Liferay might assume that it's not - this wouldn't be a technical but a configurational problem.

Also check liferay-look-and-feel.xml - there might be a compatibility field in there as well, I don't know which one takes precedence.

This setting is there because themes are built as a difference to a default theme that is built in to Liferay - and you basically state here which versions you have checked this theme to actually work with. You can specify any number of versions, as well as some wildcards (e.g. 6.1.20+)